# Android startActivityForResult() to call anotther app's activity and get back result?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have two android app "AppA" and "AppB".
AppA has a button that triggers AppB for getting details about user. AppB should return back to AppA with the necessary user information as intent extras.

MainActivity in AppA:

```kotlin
 private const val USER_REQUEST_CODE = 0xdafe
```

```kotlin
// Get user Button Click Handler function
    fun getUserInfo(){
        val userIntent = this.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.appb")
        if(userIntent!= null){
          currentActivity.startActivityForResult(userIntent,USER_REQUEST_CODE)
        }
    }
```

```kotlin
// Function to catch the response
  override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        when(requestCode){
            USER_REQUEST_CODE -> {
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                    val userData = data.getStringExtra("user")
                    Log.d(TAG, "User Response received: $userData")
                }else{
                    Log.d(TAG,"User Response is empty")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

MainActivity in AppB:

```kotlin
// function to return back the result back to AppA.
fun returnResult(){
    val data = Intent()
    data.putExtra("user","testuser")
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data)
    finish()
}
```

With this code, App A can launch App B upon button click by calling getUserInfo() function. App B then appears and loads user information. Finally, it tries to return back to App A by calling returnResult() function. But, App A does not return back to the screen.

The onActivityResult() function on AppA, however, is called immediately after getUserInfo() function is called. It does not wait for App B's response. So, it prints `User Response is empty` every time.

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: startActivityForResult  only apply for two Activity  in same activity stack. And both activity in stand launch mode.

Comment: You might consider other Android app communication process.

Comment: https://www.developer.com/ws/android/sharing-data-from-your-android-app-with-other-apps.html